# Having issues with infinitely running nested for and while loops in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to model a population where each year the population is either growing quickly or slowly, to a max size of 5000. I then am running this while loop 5000 times to look at variation in time to 5000.

However, the loop just keeps running, and I have to stop it manually.

One odd thing is that `popVector`, which is a vector that records the size of the population each round, grows to a tremendous size, often into the tens of thousands, which I would not predict from the numbers I'm using.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

```
MAXPOP <- 5000 #Set max population
trials <- 5000
genVector <- numeric(trials)
set.seed(1)

for(j in 1:trials) {
  curr_pop <- 20 #Set initial population
  genTime <- 1
  popVector <- curr_pop;
  while(curr_pop <= MAXPOP) {
    if(genTime%%2 == 0) {
      p <- 0.25
    }
    if(genTime%%2 != 0) {
      p <- 0.5
    }
    curr_pop <- sum(rgeom(curr_pop, p)) #Set current population
    popVector <- c(popVector, curr_pop)
    genTime <- genTime + 1
  }
  genVector[j] <- genTime
}
```

Comment: It's reasonable to expect `popVector` to be tens of thousands of elements long. It would be 5000 elements if you removed the while loop entirely, so it only takes a few iterations of your while loop before you will have a `popVector` that is tens of thousands of elements long.

Comment: This is where my confusion lies then, because, if I run the while loop  once, the average length of the popVector is around 10-15. And I reinitialize my popVector each round, so I'm confused why it continues to grow.

Comment: My mistake. Since you reset it on each iteration of the for loop, my explanation is wrong. The two (one now deleted) answers are correct. You don't test that `curr_pop` could be 0, in which case you get stuck in the while loop.

Comment: @MichaelLough-Stevens The sum of independent geometric RV is a negative binomial RV. See function `rnbinom`. Also growing `popVector` via `popVector <- c(popVector, ...)` is extremely slow as the vector gets larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rgeom` function returns a vector of random numbers, with as many elements as the first argument. With a small first argument, and a second argument close to 1, it is a matter of time before it returns a set of all zeros, after which your `curr_pop <- sum(rgeom(curr_pop, p))` will remain 0 forever.

You could work around that by wrapping that call in a while loop to check for 0 sum and resetting `curr_pop` to something else, for example:

```
while (T) {
    curr_pop <- sum(rgeom(curr_pop, p)) #Set current population
    if (curr_pop > 0) break
    else curr_pop <- 1
}
```

The iteration step 2826 mentioned by @Havik23 is because of the `set.seed(1)` call. This way always the same sequence of random numbers will be generated. If you want your program to be *more random*, you might want to comment out that call.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be in your while loop.  When I run the code curr_pop gets sets to zero on the 2826 iteration of your for loop.  I"m not familiar enough with the rgeom function, but that's the place to investigate what would cause it to return a zero.

Comment: You are correct, that would cause the while loop to run infinitely, your logic seems sound! To correct for the error, I inserted the following code at the end of my while loop: if(curr_pop <= 0){break}. Now the while loop will break if the population hits zero, though it's not ideal, since I have no idea which populations had an error and should be excluded from the analyses.